# class attributes are not changing after reaching specific width in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
$(window).on('resize', function (event) {  
if ($('body').width() <= 480) {


            $("circle").attr("cx", 115).attr("cy", 80).attr("r", 70).attr("transform", "rotate(-84, 100, 99)");
            $("#skills .row [class*=col-]").toggleClass("col-xs-6 col-xs-12");

        }
}
```

My code is it should remove the attributes and assign the give value once it reaches width < 480. But this is not happening when i inspect the element and set the screen size as iphone 5s( width:320px). May i know the reason why its not changing? I even changed the body.width() to window.width() but its not working.

Comment: What do you mean by _"set the screen size?"_ If you're adjusting the width of the viewport to a smaller size **after** your page has loaded and the width of the viewport is above `480px` then your code won't do anything when your resize it later because it has **already run**. If you _"set"_ the page to the smaller viewport size when the page is loaded your code should run. If you need it to work anytime the viewport is resized you should place the code in an event handler for the `resize` event for the `window`. I'd also use a flag to you don't repeatedly set the values.

Comment: So what do i need to do inorder to execute that code once it is opened in iphone 5s?

Comment: It should run when opened on the iPhone 5s because the viewport will be small enough. How are you testing this? In your desktop browser and simply resizing down to iPhone 5s viewport size?

Comment: No i have tested using responsitaor.com

Comment: you can use jquery resize function

Comment: @arun don't change your original code unless it's from your original code and you left part of it out by accident. From what I can tell you've updated the code in your post to reflect a recent attempt using a posted answer.

Comment: Yes its from my original code i haven&#39;t updated after seeing the comments.  I thought its irrelevant but when i look through the comments they suggested me to use resize() . So then i realized that it is important to put that code  in my question inorder to get correct solution to my problem.

Comment: @arun okay, good to know. Just making sure.

Comment: @zer00ne, values do not need to be quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you attached your code to a `resize` event you need a resize event to occur for the code to run. This will not happen when the page loads. You can either remove the `resize` event handler and you code will run when the page loads and see if the `body` width matches the breakpoint requirement. Or you can use a named function (function declaration) and pass that to the event handler. Then call the named function to run the code initially and then wait for `resize` events.

If you only want to call this code one time and you're not worried about the viewport size changing above and below `480px` after initial page load, then you can just get rid of the `resize` handler and run your code.

If you want to observe the viewport width after page load and want to react to it anytime it changes above or below `480px` then you'll need to do something like I have below.

```js
var $body   = $( 'body' ),
    $rows   = $( '#skills .row [class*=col-]' ),
    $circle = $( 'circle' ),
    atOrUnderBreakpoint = false;

function onResize( e ) {

  var $width = $body.width();

  if ( $width <= 480 && !atOrUnderBreakpoint ) {

    $circle.attr( {
      cx: 115,
      cy: 80,
      r: 80,
      transform: 'rotate( -84 100 99 )'
    } );
    $rows.toggleClass( 'col-xs-6 col-xs-12' ); // Maybe use addClass() or removeClass() here?

    atOrUnderBreakpoint = true;
    console.log( 1 );

  }

  if ( $width > 480 && atOrUnderBreakpoint ) {

    // Example.
    $circle.attr( {
      cx: 50,
      cy: 50,
      r: 20,
      transform: ''
    } );

    atOrUnderBreakpoint = false;
    console.log( 2 );
  }

}

$( window ).on( 'resize', onResize );
onResize(); // Special case, don't wait for resize event this ONE time, apply right away.
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="transparent" stroke="hotpink" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>
```

Above code in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rvmvn1t4/ (slide divider side-to-side to change viewport size).

One issue I see with your code and using the `resize` event is the use of `toggeClass()`. `resize` gets called **a lot**, and the `col-xs-` class will constantly be added/removed from the elements. This will cause those elements to resize/flicker. Here's [**an example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ovc6x2by/) using `background-color`, notice it flashes between the two colors. Something similar will likely happen to your element size.

I would consider switching to `addClass()` or `removeClass()`, whichever you would need, along with setting something that will prevent your code from running more than one time after it has been applied at the breakpoint (you know, prevent flicker etc.). I used a flag in my example.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery `resize` function

```js
$('body').resize(function(){      
    console.log('body dimension changed');
    if ($('body').width() <= 480) {
        $("circle").attr("cx", 115).attr("cy", 80).attr("r", 70).attr("transform", "rotate(-84, 100, 99)");
        $("#skills .row [class*=col-]").toggleClass("col-xs-6 col-xs-12");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Won't this constantly toggle the `col-xs-` classes when under `480`? When, I'm assuming, they only want the change to happen once when below `480`?

Comment: i guess he want to check body width, when it resized

Comment: $(window).on('resize', function (event) {
    if ($('body').width() <= 520) {

        $("circle").attr("cx", 115).attr("cy", 80).attr("r", 70).attr("transform", "rotate(-84, 100, 99)");
        $("#skills .row [class*=col-]").toggleClass("col-xs-6 col-xs-12");

    }
}

sorry i already did that i have used resize function but its not happening

Comment: Yes, but if the viewport is resized again, while under `480px`, then `toggleClass()` will flip between adding and removing the `col-xs-` classes. Essentially changing the width back-and-forth between two values. Take a look at [**this JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ovc6x2by/). The color flashes as the viewport is resized. A similar affect would happen when constantly adding/removing the `.col-xs-` classes.